# How to numerically differentiate a set of unevenly time spaced quaternions in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, quaternions, numerical, derivative

I have the time evolution (unevenly spaced) of around 1000 quaternions which provides the transformation from an inertial coordinate system to a body fixed. My goal is to obtain the angular velocity of the body, so for that I need the derivative of the quaternion (or at least I think so), and I am having trouble to obtain it.

So far I have tried first to use the *gradient* function

```
time_grad = gradient(time);
dquat(1,:) = gradient(quat(1,:)) ./ (time_grad);
dquat(2,:) = gradient(quat(2,:)) ./ (time_grad);
dquat(3,:) = gradient(quat(3,:)) ./ (time_grad);
dquat(4,:) = gradient(quat(4,:)) ./ (time_grad);
```

I have also tried using a Fornberg algorithm I found online, but I think I am not obtaining good results based on the final outcome (some computations using the angular velocity which should result in something very similar to some information I already have).

These quaternions could be easily converted to Direction Cosine Matrices if you know a better method to calculate angular velocity based on DCMs.

Comment: I recommend to ask a question at math.stackexchange.com about the mathematical background first.

Comment: If you don't pass the time vector to `gradient` function, it assumes an evenly spaced time vector. So just use `gradient(quat(1,:), time)` and should be alright. If not, there are more serios mathematica problems.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answers I've tried that and the results do not seem correct either, it could also be a mistake in the way of computing the angular velocity but I'm almost sure that it is correctly implemented

Comment: Seconding thewaywewalk, that's the correct way to use `gradient`.